# Question page has an extra yellow stripe for anonymous visitors

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Visiting a question page (any question) without logging in, I see a strange yellow stripe. It does not look like an intended design element.

[image: shot]

Seen in Chrome 49 on Windows 7.

If the tour invitation is collapsed, it becomes a message on that yellow background, which makes sense.   It appears that the background is placed prematurely.

Comment: I see it too -- Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m, IE 11, Edge 20.10240.16384.0, and Firefox 45.0 on Windows 10.  Safe to say it's not a browser issue :P

Comment: I see it here in my Firefox 45.0 on Slackware 14.1 as well. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zHs6J.png

Comment: It seems it's the default layout/design. Opening 404's page (e.g. [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/-1)) also shows the yellow stripe. Whether it's intentional or not, not sure (but agree that looks weird)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch. Not sure where that come from, but I'm pushing a fix now. It should be resolved in our next production build.

Comment: Hi Kurtis, is it possible to consider [Android.SE chat room to use Material design](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/)? The meta post was probably not the best, but the core issue is to update using Material design. The additional feature requests can be considered, but very optional. Thanks!